# i18n with Next.js 14 and app directory / App Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When attempting to localize the app project, I face an issue where checking the first page ("/") leads to a 404 error. I have two languages configured:

```
/ -> 404
/en -> English
/de -> German
```

It should be

```
/ -> English
/en -> English
/de -> German
```

I want the root ("/") to display the English version and  ("/de") to show the German version.
How can I appropriately handle this in the app directory?

I'm aiming to achieve the same functionality as demonstrated in [carlogino](https://carlogino.com/blog/nextjs13-i18n), but unfortunately, I'm encountering issues, and the solution isn't working for me.

```
    "node":"18.17.0",     
    "next": "^14.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "i18next": "^23.7.6",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.2.0",
    "i18next-resources-to-backend": "^1.2.0",
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show me your App.js code please? And did you create an i18next.js file?

Comment: I haven't created an 18next.js file, and in Next.js version 14, there is no longer an app.js file.

Comment: do you have any updates? can you solve this?

Comment: Unfortunatly, not yet.@AmirFarahani

Comment: I can confirm that if u follow their documentation u will face this issue! because I have that too and still couldn't find an answer.